# Python nested Dictionary: Count the maximum number of keys for a parent key

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2

Probably my question wordings are not quite correct. Here is the question:

**Code:**

```
import jinja2
import pprint


dict = {'PRI_KEY_1': {'SEC_KEY_1': {'KEY_1': 'abcd',
                                    'KEY_2': 'wef'}},
        'PRI_KEY_2': {'SEC_KEY_2': {'KEY_3': 'cwc API',
                                    'KEY_4': 'r34f',
                                    'KEY_5': 'f4f-ef',
                                    'KEY_6': 'dse',
                                    'KEY_7': '78ik',
                                    'KEY_8': 'k9k'},
                      'SEC_KEY_1': {'KEY_9': 'kk7 API',
                                    'KEY_10': '9u',
                                    'KEY_11': 'gtgr-45gr',
                                    'KEY_12': 'ggrer',
                                    'KEY_13': 'nmb',
                                    'KEY_14': 'ekj',
                                    'KEY_15': 'das3',
                                    'KEY_16': '5lusf',
                                    'KEY_17': '3rt5hf',
                                    'KEY_18': 'f4gth',
                                    'KEY_19': 'dfghtgr',
                                    'KEY_20': 'chy',
                                    'KEY_21': 'xdvgrw'}}}
temp_list = []

for key in dict['PRI_KEY_2']:
    temp_list.append(len(dict['PRI_KEY_2'][key]))

print('Rowspan needed for PRI_KEY_2:',max(temp_list))
```

**Output:**

```
Rowspan needed for PRI_KEY_2: 13
```

**Question:**
Above code works. However, is there a better way to achieve this? 
The reason being, I am creating an html table using `jinja2` where I need to define the `rowspan` for `PRI_KEY_2` considering the maximum keys its child keys has so that the table will *look like* a table.

BTW, My Dict has 100+ `PRI_KEY_*` and many more under their child, grand child keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a generator expression into `max` to compute this

```
>>> max(len(i) for i in d['PRI_KEY_2'].values())
13
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehension. Below code will give rowspan value for each primary key

```
{primary_key:(max([len(dict[primary_key][key]) for key in dict[primary_key]])) for primary_key in dict}
# Output is {'PRI_KEY_2': 13, 'PRI_KEY_1': 2}
```